# How can I turn the frames rendered by blender in an animation into a video?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, video

I made an animation in blender, and I rendered the animation. However, when I rendered it, Blender exported the animation as individual frames and not a video. How can I turn the images into a video? Do I have to use additional software/programs?

Comment: You could use [ffmpeg](http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/), which runs on most systems and costs nothing. Alternatively, any video editing application should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Generally, you want to render the animation as individual frames and not as a video. If your computer dies in the middle of a batch render, you don't lose all your work and you can restart where you left off. See this video: https://youtu.be/dd5RT8rEPqU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open Blender and go to the video sequence editor view.
- Add->Image. Select to the folder with all you images and select them with <kbd>a</kbd> (all), <kbd>b</kbd> (box select), or shift+click (single select). Press "Add Image Strip"
- You image sequence will be added as strip
- Set start and end frame according to the strip's size.
- Go back to the default view.
- In the rendering tab of the Properties panel, make sure that "Sequencer" is checked in "Post Processing".
- In "Output", set the wished video format, compression and out file
- Render the animation (<kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd>)